# How to import a class located in another root directory folder

Tags: python

Using Python 3.7.9 and having a file directory hierarchy like this

```
Application
| |
| └── __init__.py
|
├── CLS
│     └── Article.py
│     └── __init__.py
│      
└── OUT
    └── publish.py
    └── __init__.py
```

As you can see I have the `__init__.py` located in all folders `Application`, `CLS`, and `OUT` now when I am trying to import the `Article.py` file (which contains a Python class definition) into `publish.py` like

```
from Application.CLS.Article import Article
```

or

```
from CLS.Article import Article
```

or

```
 from ...CLS.Article import Article
```

I am getting this error message

```
ModuleNotFoundError   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-8542540653f1> in <module>
----> 1 from Application.CLS.Article import Article 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Application.CLS.Article'; 'CLS.Article' is not a package
```

Why is this still happening while I have the `__init__.py` located in all folder levels?

Comment: How are you running the code and from which directory?

Comment: Thanks for reply @GeorgeImerlishvili I am using PyCharm and running the `publish.py` from the IDLE

Comment: from Application.CLS import Article?
also do you have from .Article import x in __init__.py?

Comment: Hi walker, sorry I am not getting your point!

Comment: @Behseini - I don't understand what it is about walker's comment that is unclear. There are two points - firstly try `from Application.CLS import Article` and report back. Secondly, there is a question about the contents of your `init.py`, please report back on that also.

Comment: It's worth noting that if someone asks you a question online, it's worth being as detailed with what you do understand, in the first instance. This can massively cut down on the number of conversational loops, and it can speed up the process too. Answers like "I don't understand" or "it doesn't work" are actively unhelpful, as they implicitly require your interlocutor to ask you further questions about your problem. In this case, it seems that walker has decided to drop out of the conversation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

If you are on linux, you can `cd` to the directory where you are executing your code from and run

```
export PYTHONPATH="$pwd"
```

This is a temporary fix, you will need to run this every time you open a new terminal session.

For a more permanent solution, you can hardcode the location to your code directory in your `.bashrc` file.

Or if you are on a different OS check the following link:
[PYTHONPATH](https://bic-berkeley.github.io/psych-214-fall-2016/using_pythonpath.html)

And if you are on Windows specifically:
[PYTHONPATH in Windows](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-edit-pythonpath-on-windows-eafd19840d44/)